# Any software to auto generate doxygen comment blocks?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm developing a large C++ program and I've now decided to document it with Doxygen.
There are plenty of classes, methods, functions, macros and so on. Therefore I'm searching for software that would scan my source tree and insert Doxygen comment blocks on top of every "documentable item" to let me edit them later and add details such as method descriptions and so on.

Does any such software exist?

I'm under GNU/Linux with the Code::Blocks IDE, so no Visual Studio plugins are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set Doxygen to extract non-documented items as well - that may do what you want without adding ANY comment blocks to the code yet.

After that you can create templates / macros (depends on your IDE) to create pre-formatted blocks for each type of item, as you slowly work through the code documenting items one by one.

[edit]
If you're using Visual Studio, some introspection is available on the classes and other constructs in the file, that may help.   Alternatively take a look at [Doxycomment](http://doxycomment.sourceforge.net/) - it might be some of what you want.

Comment: I'm aware of that feature, but i prefer to have those comments in the source code.

Comment: Well you can easily create *empty* templates for the blocks you would like to add.  Getting some data into those templates automatically might be trickier - but check out Doxycomment.

Comment: I'm under GNU/Linux with Code::Blocks IDE, so no VisualStudio plugins needed .

Comment: @Simone Doxy comments that simply reproduce what Doxygen can generate without them would seem to be redundant, to say the least.

Answer (score 6):

I am quite perplex here.

What is the goal of automatically generating comments ?

Comments are meant to bring additional value:

```
/**
 * \brief: finds the person based on its name
 * \param: name, the name of the person
 * \result: the person
 */
Person findPerson(Name name);
```

Is nothing but code clutter that clog my valuable screen estate. And that's about as much as can be generated automatically unfortunately... Notice in particular that I have no idea of what happens if ever the function does not find the person, which certainly seems likely: does it abort ? throws ? (what... ?) returns a default constructed object ?

On the other hand:

```
///
/// Try an exact match approach to begin with
/// Uses the double metaphone algorithm
///   if none was found as we have
///   a western european clientele
///
Person findPerson(Name name)
{
}
```

is much more interesting!

- Now I know what is this strange collection of `if` that seems to be performing some kind of sound recognition...
- I know its name so I can look it up on Internet to check its implementation (functionality)
- And I know why it was selected and thus when I should reevaluate its use (fits a western european clientele so if we develop on arabic market it'll need adaptation...)

Unfortunately, that's not going to be generated automatically.

Comment: I think that question is very valuable. In a good project, there are plenty of comments all over, as most routines can be expected to be non-trivial. For a person about to learn or maintain the code, each single (intelligent) line is valuable.

In case you have, say, 30.000 lines of barely and badly documented code, such a small tool as requested by the author can be a bliss, if you want to read throught the code and create a documentation by yourself.

Comment: You are forgetting the vast number of lines that are written not for one's joy but as pure, sober, dry contract work, where someone != you has set up a coding style. You can try to fight the inevitable or you just try to adapt with the least possible effort.

Comment: @Vroomfondel: there's a famous (and potentially made up) story about a new manager waltzing in and asking that from now at the end of each week the developers should report to him the number of lines they added to the codebase. End of the week, the report of the seniormost developer comes in: -16,000 lines. If you find yourself in such a situation, it may be time to look for a better job; someone wasting everyone's time in a position of power is never good.

Comment: @MatthieuM. agreed, but there are circumstances where you simply don't have any other option than adapting. Not everybody lives close to Silly Valley or Redmond.

Comment: Yes comments are valuable, but it takes an unethical amount of time to type those "/**" and "///" as well as "\brief"

Comment: @MatthaeusGaiusCaesar: IDES can autocomplete it... but to be honest, nowadays I favor the Rust style of comments. Just `///` as a prefix, a short sentence for the brief (without `\brief`), maybe a paragraph if it's there's something special about the parameters, or enumerating the failing conditions (no `\param` nor `\result`) and markdown sections `/// # Section` for invariants, safety invariants, exceptions, algorithmic complexity, example, etc... as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so this is an old post, but I just had the same problem and I've found doxymacs. It integrates nicely with emacs and generates doxymacs comments for your functions and files. After putting the .el file in your emacs path you can add a hook to make it available whenever you open a C/C++ file "(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook'doxymacs-mode)" and comment the functions with C-c d f and the files with C-c d i, there are other comment types available, just check the project page: http://doxymacs.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

There are some c/cpp parsers in python, that might be used for your specific purpose. However, I have never used those yet.

For a similar objective, I wrote a python script that adds "doxygen-headers" to the methods in the header-file majorly. I have used regular expression, and I have a version that adds "doxygen headers" in the source file for the method-definitions (use RE_M_DEFINITION, at method-lookup).

**Code for your reference, as below:**

> genDoxygenC.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import re

################################################################

RE_MULTI_LINE_PARAMS = ".*"

# could be used in header/source files, for method-definition extraction
RE_M_DEFINITION  = r'[A-Za-z0-9*]*\s*[A-Za-z0-9_*]+\s*[A-Za-z0-9_~:*]+\(.*\)\s*\{\s*.*?\s*\}'   #TODO:  this needs to be more generic to                                                        be able to parse for methods only
# used in header-files in major for method declaration extraction
RE_M_DECLERATION = r"[A-Za-z0-9*]*\s*[A-Za-z0-9_*]+\s+[A-Za-z0-9_~*]+\s*\(%s\)\s*;"%RE_MULTI_LINE_PARAMS

################################################################

# C/CPP CMD List
cmdList = ["for","if","while","switch","else"];

##########################
# exit errors enumerations
class EErrors() :
    IncorrectUsage, FileOpenError = range(2)

###################
# exception handler
def handleException(e, mssg) :
    if e == EErrors.IncorrectUsage :
        print "Usage : "+mssg
        elif e == EErrors.FileOpenError :
        print "Unable to open \"" + mssg + "\" file !"
    sys.exit(2)

###############################
# creates method doxygen header 
def frameDoxygenHeader(param_count, paramList) :
    commentStr = "/**\n * @brief \n"    
    if param_count > 0 :
        for param in paramList:
            commentStr = commentStr + " * @param \n"

    # comment for return values
    commentStr = commentStr + " * @return \n */ \n"

    return commentStr

##############################################
# adds the doxygen comments, on method lookup
def addDoxygenComment(file_name, funcList) :
    try:    
        fh = open(file_name, 'rb')
        f_old = open(file_name, 'r+') 
    except:
                handleException(EErrors.FileOpenError, file_name)

    f_new = open(out_file_name, "w")
    final_loc = 0
    next_split_loc = 0
    last_write_loc = 0
    fContent = str(f_old.read())
    for func in funcList:
        SEARCH_TEXT = func  
        print "SEARCH_TEXT "+SEARCH_TEXT
            fsize =  os.path.getsize(file_name)
            bsize = fsize
            word_len = len(SEARCH_TEXT)
        fh.seek(0)

        # doxygen comment header generation
        paramListStr = re.findall(r'\(.*\)', SEARCH_TEXT)
        paramListStr[0] = paramListStr[0].replace('(','')
        paramListStr[0] = paramListStr[0].replace(')','')
        paramList = paramListStr[0].split(",")
        comment_text = frameDoxygenHeader(len(paramList),paramList)

        while True:
                    found = 0
                    pr = fh.read(bsize)
                    pf = pr.find(SEARCH_TEXT, next_split_loc)
                    if pf > -1:
                            found = 1
                            pos_dec = fh.tell() - (bsize - pf)
                            fh.seek(pos_dec + word_len)
                            bsize = fsize - fh.tell()
                print "Case-I:"+str(fh.tell())
                    if fh.tell() < fsize:
                                   seek = fh.tell() - word_len + 1
                                   print "seek"+str(seek)
                       fh.seek(seek)
                                   if 1==found:
                                           final_loc = seek
                           next_split_loc = final_loc + word_len - 1
                                           print "loc: "+str(final_loc)
                       print "Case-IIa:"+str(fh.tell())
                    else:
                                   break

        # create file with doxygen comments
        if final_loc != -1 :
            #f_new.write(fContent[0:final_loc-1]);
            #not to miss the contents, between two methods          
            if last_write_loc < final_loc :
                f_new.write(fContent[last_write_loc:final_loc-1]);

            f_new.write(comment_text);
            f_new.write(fContent[final_loc-1:next_split_loc])
            last_write_loc = next_split_loc

            #reset values
            final_loc = -1
        else:
            print "method not found !!"

    # last of the file should not be missed either
    if last_write_loc < len(fContent) :
        f_new.write(fContent[last_write_loc:]);
    f_new.close()
    f_old.close()


#############################################
#############################################
# main execution of the code starts from here
#############################################
argc = len(sys.argv)
if (argc == 1 or argc >2)  :
    handleException(EErrors.IncorrectUsage, "genDoxygenC.py <cpp source file>")
else :
    # Correct Input as per USAGE.
    fname = sys.argv[1]
    out_file_name = fname+'.doxygen'
    fcontent=''
    try:
        # read file
        fh = open(fname)
        fcontent = fh.read()
    #   print fcontent
    except:
        handleException(EErrors.FileOpenError, fname)

    # lookup for methods in file
    funcList = re.findall(RE_M_DECLERATION, fcontent, re.VERBOSE)
    fh.close()

    funcListCopy = funcList
    for fStr in funcListCopy :
        fStr = fStr.lstrip()
        startW = fStr.partition(' ')[0]
        startW = fStr.partition('(')[0]
        #print startW
        if startW in cmdList :
            # invalid method extraction
            funcList.remove(fStr)   

    # process valid methods-list for doxygen header
    addDoxygenComment(fname, funcList)
    #print funcList
```

> **Usage ::** ./genDoxygenC.py file.h

This will generate

> file.h.doxygen

and then, you can probably check the *doxygen-headers-added-file*, with *original-header-file* using any diff-tool.

**Example :** *meld file.h file.h.doxygen*

**Note::** The script might skip constructors, with new versions definitions/declarations like;

S() : n(7)) {};

Comment: Could you give the file itself because copying from here just ruins the code.

Answer (score 1):

The posting for genDoxygenC.py has numerous index/whitespace errors.  Since Python program flow is dependent on proper indexing I am concerned that the inner block the addDoxygenComment method might not have been correct.  Is there a chance you could post the actual source file to here?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a free Doxygen generator for C++ that uses the macro explorer plugin for Visual Studio 2015, which can be found here:
https://github.com/cppocl/visual_studio_macros

Answer (score 0):

Check your editor.  I have been using the CodeWright editor, and it has a feature called selective display. Configured properly I can press the icon, and only the first line of function definitions is displayed.  Alternatively, you can use block collapse/expand in some other editors.  Either way makes it easy to speedily navigate through your source code to headers/definitions, etc and then paste some boiler plate comment to be filled in later.  I often use my own search tags, e.g. *COMMENTME* in my code that I can get back to with simple searches.